# How to change title of columns dynamically while adding columns to table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-table

Here is a working codepen for editing table cells:
https://codepen.io/gges5110/pen/GLPjYr?editors=0010

the adding column function is as below:

```
handleAddColumn = () => {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    const newColumn = {
      title: 'age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
    };
```

How do I make it so that for every time I click on 'add a column' it will change the column title to 'age 1', 'age 2', 'age 3', ...?

Comment: Try this approach `handleAddColumn = () => {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    const ageArray = columns.filter(item => item.title.includes('age'));
    const newColumn = {
      title: 'age'+ageArray.length,
      dataIndex: 'age'+ageArray.length,
    };

    this.setState({
      columns: [...columns, newColumn]
    })
  }`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what your meant:

You can add number of columns to this.state

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
      count: 2,
      cols: 1,
    };
  }
```

and then change the state in the handleAddColumn

```
  handleAddColumn = () => {
    const { columns, cols } = this.state;
    const newColumn = {
      title: `age ${cols}`,
      dataIndex: 'age',
    };

    this.setState({
      columns: [...columns, newColumn],
      cols: cols+1
    })
  }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
 handleAddColumn = () => {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    const ageArray = columns.filter(item => item.dataIndex === 'age');
    
    const newColumn = {
      title: 'age'+ ageArray.length,
      dataIndex: 'age',
    };

    this.setState({
      columns: [...columns, newColumn]
    })
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this, I have used same count state you have added,
need to update it on addColumn.

```
handleAddColumn = () => {
const { columns } = this.state;
const newColumn = {
  title: `age ${this.state.count}`,
  dataIndex: 'age',
};
this.setState({
  count: this.state.count + 1,
});
this.setState({
  columns: [...columns, newColumn]
})
```

}